# Push Docker Images from Azure Devops Build artifacts to Image Repository

Tags: docker, kubernetes, azure-devops, docker-registry, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am building an Azure DevOps pipeline using a yml file.

In the yml definition I have two stages, one is to build docker images , second stage is to push these images to ACR. I am able to store docker image as build artifact in the first step. I can also download build artifact into $(Pipeline.Workspace). I could not find a way to push image from $(Pipeline.Workspace) to Container registry as docker save does not have parameter to reference $(Pipeline.Workspace) workspace directory.

```
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Push Image to Repository
  inputs:
    command: push
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Build and push an image to container registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/containers/acr-template?view=azure-devops#how-we-build-your-pipeline)

```
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build and push stage
  jobs:  
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build job
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        repository: $(imageRepository)
        dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        tags: |
          $(tag)
```

You can refer to this thread [How to build docker image and push to azure container registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60234813/how-to-build-docker-image-and-push-to-azure-container-registry)

Comment: How do you manage access into ACR from the pipeline? All I'm getting is "##[error]denied: requested access to the resource is denied".